# query in hibernate with annotations

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, taglib, hibernate-annotations

when i try to complete select with hibernate, thrown this exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: formato is not mapped [from formato]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3420)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3309)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
```

i check my object annotations and think that its ok, this is the code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="formato")
public class Formato implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5849413670083213438L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="formato")
    private String formato;
    @Column(name="tipoItem")
    private int tipoItem;
```

in BD the atributtes have the same name

obviously put getters and setters, and my DAO:

```
@Transactional
    public List<Formato> findAllFormatos() {
        Transaction tx = null;
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            List formatos = session.createQuery("from formato").list();
            System.out.println("Pase :'D");
            tx.commit();
            return formatos;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    }
```

finally controller but i think that problem is in the DAO

```
@RequestMapping(value = "timbre", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirigir(@RequestParam("id") int id, Model model) {

        Timbre t = null;
        if (id == 1){
            t = new Timbre();
            model.addAttribute("t", t);

            List<Formato> formatos= timbreDAO.findAllFormatos();
            model.addAttribute("formatos", formatos);


            return "formTimbre";

        }   
        else if (id == 2)
            return "modificarTimbre";
        else if (id == 3)
            return "eliminarTimbre";
        else if (id == 4)
            return "buscarTimbre";
        else
            return "timbre";

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the HQL , you should use the java class name and property name of the mapped @Entity instead of the actual table name and column name , so the HQL should be :

```
List<Formato> formatos = (List<Formato>)session.createQuery("from Formato").list();
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that exception if you do not have the annotated entity declared in SessionFactory. 
If you are using spring, then in the sessionFactory Bean specify the following. It could be the .cfg file also.

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
         <list>
 <value>com.somefolder.Formato</value>
</list>
</property>
```

Comment: Yes, also in the HQL it has to be "from Formato f"

Comment: yes, you're right but i found i better solution without write each object: 
<property name="packagesToScan">
   <array>
    <value>com.mufi.objeto</value>
   </array>
  </property>
but now thrown this exception: 
Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: persistent class not known: int

Comment: you may have to use Integer in place of int in the mapping file

Comment: Also see all the files which hav mapping, it happens if he annotations are not properly configured.